# Threejs and jspdf: add set of images issue

Tags: async-await, three.js, jspdf

I am trying to create a pdf containing 4 images from different points of view of a threejs scene. For the pdf I'm using jspdf. The problem is that after the first set of images, the other ones get the first image in the set identical to the first of the previous set. For each set I create a threejs group of items to be added and then removed in the following cycle after the 4th image has been taken.

```
    btn2.addEventListener('click', async function(){
    console.log('Triggered')
    

    var doc= new jsPDF()

    

    for(let k=0; k<routeList.length; k++){

        let val = k+1
        
        let cR = routeList[k]
        
        scene.remove(scene.getObjectByName(currentRoute))
        currentRoute = val
        group = new THREE.Group();
        group.name = currentRoute
        $('#tbl tbody').empty();

        for (let i=0; i<cR.length; i++){
            let streetPoly = cR[i]['coordinates']
            let coordinates = []
            for (let j=0; j<streetPoly.length; j++){
                coordinates.push({'x': streetPoly[j][0], 'y': streetPoly[j][1], 'z': 0.5})
            }

            let color = cR[i]['color']
            let width = cR[i]['width']
            let speed = cR[i]['speed']

            $('#tbl tbody').append(
                
                + "<td>" + 'RouteSegment_' + i+1 + "</td>"
                + "<td>" + width + "</td>"
                + "<td>" + speed + '</td>""'
            )
            
            let polyShape = new THREE.Shape(coordinates.map((coord) => new THREE.Vector2(coord.x, coord.y)))
            
            let polyGeometry = new THREE.ShapeGeometry(polyShape);
            
            polyGeometry.setAttribute("position", new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute(coordinates.map(coord => [coord.x, coord.y, coord.z]).flat(), 3))
            let polygon = new THREE.Mesh(polyGeometry, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: color, side: THREE.DoubleSide}))
            
            group.add(polygon);
            polygon.rotation.x = -0.5 * Math.PI

            
        }
        scene.add(group)
        renderer.setAnimationLoop(animate);


        
        
        let imgData= renderer.domElement.toDataURL()

        let img= new Image()

        img.src= imgData

        doc.addImage(img,'png',30, 20, 70,70)

        scene.rotation.y= 1.5

        animate()

        imgData = renderer.domElement.toDataURL()

        img =new Image()

        img.src= imgData

        doc.addImage(img,'png',110, 20, 70,70)

        scene.rotation.y= 3

        animate()

        imgData = renderer.domElement.toDataURL()

        img =new Image()

        img.src= imgData

        doc.addImage(img,'png',30, 100, 70,70)

        scene.rotation.y= 4.5

        animate()

        imgData = renderer.domElement.toDataURL()

        img = new Image()

        img.src= imgData    

        doc.addImage(img,'png',110, 100, 70,70)

        scene.rotation.y= 0

        await doc.html(document.getElementById("tbl").innerHTML, {
        callback: function (doc) {
            return doc;
        },

        x: 10,
        y: 190,
        
        });

        // doc.autoTable({html:'#tbl', theme:'striped', startY:190})

        doc.insertPage(1)
        doc.setPage(1);
    }

    var blob = doc.output("blob")

    saveAs(blob,'report.pdf')

})
```